# Annotation processor output in maven

Tags: java, maven, annotation-processing

I'm using JSR 269 as a way to analyze code during compilation and to fail it if needed.
I'm having troubles with displaying output of my annotation processor in maven (Ant does show the output)
I'm using javax.annotation.processing.Messager to display warnings and errors, but in maven I don't see it's output. (I do know it runs though, because it generates code like it should).
Any ideas?

Comment: How does the processor output messages? How do you invoke it?

Comment: Does the output show if you invoke maven with the `-X` parameter?

Comment: @matt b I'm using javax.annotation.processing.Messager to display warnings: `_messager=processingEnv.getMessager();` @Jorn: I don't use the -X parameter, the processor is listed as a service provider

Comment: I was asking more about how the processor outputs it's messages - to a logger, to standard out, etc?

Comment: The messager API provides a way to output messages to stdout. It supposed to display compilation warnings, just like the compiler does.

Comment: The only answer below isn't accepted. Is there some other answer that is more correct at this point in time?

Comment: I had to attend to other stuff (our POC should be released soon) but I will try and update soon.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you are running into a Maven bug or better a bug in the compiler plugin - [MCOMPILER-66](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-66). When it comes to annotation processing the compiler plugin has several problems, eg also [MCOMPILER-62](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-62). Really the best option imo is to disable annotation processing for the compiler plugin and use the [*maven-processor-plugin*](https://code.google.com/p/maven-annotation-plugin/). In this [blog post](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/HibernateMetamodelGenerator110Final) you can see how to use it. It looks like this:

```
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
            <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.7</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>process</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>process</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>process-sources</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

Note also how the annotation processor dependency is nicely scoped to the plugin only.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by enabling showWarnings flag in the maven-compiler-plugin configuration:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
         <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
       </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

See also https://github.com/Cosium/annotation-processor-logger#enable-all-logging-levels

Comment: Note that this not only enables `WARNING` and `MANDATORY_WARNING`, but also `NOTE` and `OTHER`, which will be displayed by Maven as `INFO`.

Comment: This works.  You may also need `<verbose>true</verbose>`, especially if you use `<fork>true</fork>`.