# Debug Annotation Processor

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I am getting the following error when compiling code that uses my annotation processor:

```
error: Could not instantiate an instance of processor 'com.mycompany.AutoWrapperProcessor'
```

Any tips for how to debug this? The error output is not useful at all. Is there any way to get more verbose errors?

Comment: If you are using maven, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12822087/4848659 may help you.

Comment: Can you share a little more about your environment?  Are you using a build system?  How are you including the processor?  A jar?

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that my processor was not public. Makes sense -- the compiler needs to have access to the class in order to create it.